# How do I make the background color change?

Tags: java, swing, background, awt, listener

I am working on a program that has 5 different color radio buttons, and when clicked, the background should change to the corresponding color. My background is not changing.
I cannot for the life of me figure out what is wrong with my code. Can someone out there help me find my problem? Thank you!
My code is as follows:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if (blue.getState()) f.setBackground(Color.blue);
    else if (red.getState()) f.setBackground(Color.red);
    else if (yellow.getState()) f.setBackground(Color.yellow);
    else if (pink.getState()) f.setBackground(Color.pink);
    else if (gray.getState()) f.setBackground(Color.gray);
} //end of actionPerformed method

public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
{
}
```

Comment: You using `JRadioButton` or `RadioButton`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More than likely you're using `java.awt.CheckBox` components (from [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17820264/checkboxes-not-showing-up)) which respond to `ItemListeners` but not `ActionListeners`. Therefore move your code to the `itemStateChanged` method

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {

    if (blue.getState()) {
        f.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    } else if (red.getState()) {
        f.setBackground(Color.RED);
    } else if (yellow.getState()) {
        f.setBackground(Color.YELLOE);
    } else if (pink.getState()) {
        f.setBackground(Color.PINK);
    } else if (gray.getState()) {
        f.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    }
}
```

- Use braces to delimit scope
- Notice the use of newer uppercase `Color` constants
- AWT is an old limited UI library compared to the newer lightweight [Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/) which is feature rich. Swing `JCheckBoxes` support `ActionListeners`